# How to stretch a background image to full length of screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, view, background

In the home screen of my app I have to get the background image to stretch the length of the screen. But I have a translucent toolbar that the background image will not go under. 
I have tree buttons on the screen but the image just goes over the buttons and i cannot bring set the buttons to bring to front because the control for doing so is disabled.
Any ideas of how to make it stretch the full length of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should provide a set of images in the correct sizes and aspect ratios, as follows:

**iPad**

- Standard : 1024x768 = myAsset.png
- Retina : 2048x1536 = myAsset@2x.png

**iPhone**

- Standard : 320x480 = myAsset.png
- Retina : 640x960 = myAsset@2x.png
- 4-inch : 640x1136 = myAsset-568h@2x.png

. . . as shown above the file-name is used to instruct UIKit which version to use for a given device.

**Alternative**

If you're unable to provide the image in the correct sizes, you can create a custom UIImageView background view, and set the ***contentMode*** property on this view to UIViewContentModeAspectFit or UIViewContentModeAspectFill.

**Use Vector Graphics?**

A 3rd (not yet widely-used) option might be to use vector graphics. Either by reading in assets produced by an designer-focused tool like Illustrator or by using a developer focused tool like [PaintCode](http://theindustry.cc/2012/03/21/paintcode-paint-cocoa-drawing-code/).